# Exception Occurring Infinitely in Content Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

**First, this is a simplified version from a wizard control using MVVM. The problem is just easier to reproduce as described below**

After much narrowing down, I have resolved an infinite exception in my code to be due to the WPF `ContentControl`. However, I have yet to figure out how to handle it, other than try-catch wrapping all of my possible instantiation code. Here is sample code that reproduces this...any help on how to keep this infinite exception from occurring would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Details**

To sum up, the problem is that if the content control changes its contents, and the thing being loaded in throws an exception, then it will throw, then retry the load, causing the throw again and again.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name ="Main">
    <Grid>

        <ContentControl Name="bar" Content="{Binding ElementName=Main, Path=foo}"/>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="20" Width="50"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private UserControl _foo;
    public UserControl foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set { _foo = value; OnPropertyChanged("foo"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foo = new UserControl1();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foo = new UserControl2();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**UserControl1 is blank and all default**

**UserControl2.xaml.cs**

```
public UserControl2()
{

  InitializeComponent();
  throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Could you please extend more on how the ContentControl is causing the infinite loop?

Comment: Delete all that and create a proper ViewModel and remove `INotifyPropertyChanged` from the UI where it does not belong and use proper DataBinding and DataTemplates and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite exception"? An infinite loop? A StackOverflowException?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I added additional details that hopefully help clarify. It is the content change rendering that will continuously retry to render even though there is an exception.

Comment: @HighCore This is the simplified version, but this happens in production code that is using DataBindings and ViewModels. It is a WizardFramework that swaps out the user control as the steps move along.

Comment: @Sphinxxx I added clarification in the post, but I mean: the content tries to change but throws an exception, then the content tries to change again and again and again. Which causes the exception to continue forever.

Comment: Found conflicting data...figuring out

Comment: Seems like the issue here is that your control is throwing exceptions??  You're trying to solve the symptom and not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind ContentControl to MainWindow.  Instead use [DataTemplates](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/data-templates) to select the content for the MainWindow.  One example-contrived way of doing it is to bind the ContentControl's Content to the DataContext of the MainWindow.

First some observable test data is needed.  The specifics of this data are not important.  The main point is to have two different classes of test data from which to choose - **TestData.cs**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace fwWpfDataTemplate
{
    // Classes to fill TestData
    public abstract class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    public class Student : Person { }
    public class Employee : Person
    {
        float _salary;
        public float Salary
        {
            get { return _salary; }
            set
            {
                _salary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Salary");
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestData : ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        public TestData()
            : base(new List<Person>()
            { 
                new Student { Name = "Arnold" },
                new Employee { Name = "Don", Salary = 100000.0f }
            }) { }
    }
}
```

Then add DataTemplates to MainWindow's resources - **MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="fwWpfDataTemplate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:me="clr-namespace:fwWpfDataTemplate"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type me:Student}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Student"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type me:Employee}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Employee"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Salary"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Salary}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Change Data Context" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note: instead of the StackPanels the contents of the DataTemplates could be UserControl1, UserControl2, etc.

Then add some code to change the data context - **MainWindow.cs**:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace fwWpfDataTemplate
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        TestData testData = new TestData();
        int testIndex = -1;
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            testIndex = (testIndex + 1) % testData.Count;
            this.DataContext = testData[testIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy.